# How to calculate number of downtimes and Total downtime and average downtime in the below xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

How to calculate downtime and average downtime and total down time?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation. It'll make it easier to understand

Comment: @trope Don't edit your question to remove the content once you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The overallAvailability is an attribute of the tag ServiceAvailabiltyReport, so your code needs to look like this.

```
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

sum = 0; count = 0; avgTime = 0
for fName in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    tree = ET.parse(fName)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for tag in root.iter('ServiceAvailabilityReport'):
        sum += float(tag.attrib["overallAvailability"])
        count += 1
        avgTime = sum / count

print avgTime
```

Also, just a a side note, the xml file you posted had some issues including missing closing tags etc. I'm not sure if this is true for all your files, or if it is an artefact of the copy paste.

Comment: Can you just accumulate the count till the end, and then divide by count in the end?

Comment: @trope this isn't a tutorial service - if you have another on-topic question, please ask it.

Comment: @trope. I'm sorry but I don't have time today to help you. Other people may perhaps be able to offer help if you wrote at least an attempt at these additional questions first.